# How to make a method recursive?

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

In the last days I created a method which one gets the Files in a folder and the files in the 1st Subfolders but not in the subfolders of those Subfolders.

To explain it better:

That's the Folder:

```
//Folder1
//├file1.txt
//├subfolder1
//|├file2.txt
//|└subfolder3
//| └file3.txt
//└subfolder2
// └subfolder4
//  └subfolder5
//   └file4.txt
```

and that's what I get:

```
//Folder1
//├file1.txt
//└subfolder1
// └file2.txt
```

and that's how I would have it in the Folder where I copy it:

```
//Folder2
//├file1.txt
//├subfolder1___file2.txt
//├subfolder1___subfolder3___file3.txt
//└subfolder2___subfolder4___subfolder5___file4.txt
```

and tha'ts how I have it:

```
//Folder2
//├file1.txt
//└subfolder1___file2.txt
```

(to understand those structures better, read the code)

Current Code:

```
private void GetFiles(string filePath)
{
    //filepath = "C:\Example\folder1"
    string[] installfiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
    string appdatafolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    string[] SelectedFiles;

    foreach (string file in installfiles)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

        if (!Directory.Exists(appdatafolder + "\\temp"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(appdatafolder + "\\temp");
        }
        if (!File.Exists(sourcefoldervalueLabel.Text + "\\" + fileName))
        {
            File.Copy(filePath + filename, appdatafolder + "\\temp\\" + fileName, true);
        }
    }

//here I would make it recursive.

    if (Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)).Length >= 1)
    {
        string[] subdirectoryies = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath);
        foreach (string directory in subdirectoryies)
        {
            string[] SubFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
            string directoryname = Path.GetFileName(directory);

            foreach (string file in SubFiles)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
                if (!File.Exists(sourcefoldervalueLabel.Text + "\\" + directoryname + "\\" + filename))
                {
                     File.Copy(file, appdatafolder + "\\temp\\" + directoryname + "___" + filename, true); // here I copy it into Folder2 but instead of creating subfolders I add "___" between the subfolder-name and the file-name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if I would make it recursive at the point I set (look Code), I could get the Files in every Folder (I think otherwise tell me).

So my Question is :

How Can I make repeat the "marked" Code every time if there is a subfolder in the current folder?

I hope the question is understandable (otherwhise I'll explain it).

As always You can correct me in every way its possible :).

Have a great day,

Gentle.

Comment: You can find some help in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19067063/2259589

Comment: this is similar to what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25360943/451540

Comment: @Millas if you mean the most voted comment in your link... i think i said when it shall stop to avoid an invinitive loop

Comment: @thumbmunkeys and i think ineed to save the subdirectory name everytime to add it to the filename so i have no clue how ... some ideas?

Comment: Why downvote i try to learn ;) You guys could correct me instead of down voting ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Perfect code for  this situation would be Right Tree algorithm.

Comment: and what is this "Right Tree algorithm"?

Comment: its a recursive algorithm. you can create a custom class of your node type which you will pass as nodes, i have a custom made but it is binary tree algorithm. with few little changes you can use it.

Comment: I would love to get your Code so i can change it, so i can use it :) (i wont abuse it :) )

Comment: this code is console based. currently it is saving a character in binaraytreenode class there your variable and data type will be store like locations of directories.

Comment: i know you want try it. but code is tool long for comment.

Comment: Code should somewhere in this blog. i put it there when i was in university. and there many other use full algorithms and data structures  http://csharpcode13.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it after looking up for some recursive programming

Final Code :

```
private void GetFilesinDirectory(string directory,string targetdirectory)
{
    string [] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
    if(directories.Length >= 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < directories.Length; i++)
        {
            GetFilesinDirectory(directories[i], targetdirectory);
        }
    }
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
    if (files.Length >= 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
            string filenamewithoutdeploy = filename.Replace(".deploy", string.Empty);

            string directoryunderscoreName = directory.Replace(InstallfoldervalueLabel.Text + "\\Appfiles\\", String.Empty)
                                                .Replace("\\","___");
            string directoryname = directory.Replace(InstallfoldervalueLabel.Text + "\\Appfiles\\", String.Empty);

            if (!File.Exists(sourcefoldervalueLabel.Text + "\\" + directoryname + "\\" + filenamewithoutdeploy))
            {
                File.Copy(directory + "\\" + filename, targetdirectory + directoryunderscoreName + "___" + filename, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would loove to get some corrections,suggestions :)